# In Sword Art Online Ordinal Scale, how does Asuna know about the boss' healing ability?

Tags: sword-art-online

The final fight against the level 100 boss has two parts to it:

1. Kirito and his usual group of friends go up against it alone.
2. Asuna, and everyone else from ALO and GGO join in.

In the 1st half of the battle, Kirito and friends basically get annihilated. In this first part, they observe that the boss will heal itself with a tree and drop of water.

[image]
[image] [image]

---

In the 2nd half of the battle where everyone is in, the boss attempts to heal itself again. But Asuna tells everyone to block the drop of water to stop the healing.

[image] [image]

Asuna wasn't there yet when the boss first healed itself. She wasn't watching either as she was talking to Yuuna and not in full dive.

How did she know about the move to tell everyone to block it? Is this a plot hole? Or is there an explanation to it?

Comment: This is probably just a matter of the writers of the scene missing that detail. It could be explained with someone who was there filling her in on the boss's fighting patterns, given it'd be important for her to know what it's capable of, but who knows if there's a real explanation.

Comment: Maybe from a similar pattern from new aincrad.

Answer (score 2):

If Asuna is well-learned (or more likely just because she played ALfheim Online, whose lore fiddles with Norse mythology), she may have known that in Norse mythology, the dew that falls from the tree Yggdrasil carries the power of life. In that case, she must have connected the dots instantly after seeing the tree and the dropping dew, and/or perhaps also after hearing the healing SFX that started playing at the same time.

It is interesting to note that Yggdrasil in ALfheim Online shelters the capital city of the game, and that Asuna was also a hostage at the top of Yggrasil for a whole cour.

From [*Prose Edda/Gylfaginning, 16*](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Prose_Edda/Gylfaginning):

> An ash I know
>
> Hight Ygdrasil;
>
> A high, holy tree
>
> With white clay sprinkled.
>
> Thence comes the dews
>
> That fall in the dales.
>
> Green forever it stands
>
> Over Urd's fountain.
>
> The dew which falls on the earth from this tree men call honey-fall, and it is the food of bees.

From *Prose Edda/Gylfaginning, 58*:

> In a place called Hodmimer's-hold are concealed two persons during Surt's fire, called Lif and Lifthraser. They feed on the morning dew. From these so numerous a race is descended that they fill the whole world with people, as is here said:
>
> Lif and Lifthraser
>      Will lie hid
>
> In Hodmimer's-holt.
>
> The morning dew
>
> They have for food.
>
> From them are the races descended.

Answer (score -1):

I think that stuff from anime like that may not have to make sense, because her spontaneously noticing just basically was a way for Kirito to win... she also may have just been an observant person?

Comment: I don't think that's correct. Asuna is not only a mere assistant character, is one of the main characters on the series.

Comment: Even though she is a main character, lots of times things in anime JUST DON'T MAKE SENSE. I also don't know how Asuna being a main character debunks my theory that also she may have just been observant. You also may just want to rewatch the episode....